# Build pipeline for service fabric app on Azure devops

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, continuous-deployment

[image]I am trying to create a build pipeline on AzureDevops for a service fabric application on my GitHub repository. But after I select from my repository (GitHub) I cant see the Service fabric application template among the templates shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service fabric template is "hidden" under visual designer build view:

[image]

to get to the visual designer view, you need to do this (on the screen shot below) on the very first screen you get to when you create a new build:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much . I was not using the visual designer :)